# In Xcode, the phone simulator orientation is not in portrait form?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8

I'm using Swift SpriteKit. This is my scene for an app I am currently making:

[image]

I made the width and height of the frame so it works with the iphone 7, but when I run it in the iPhone 7 simulator it looks like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the simulator is in horizontal orientation:

Open up the simulator, in the menu bar go to Hardware > Rotate Left/Right

Comment: Oops I forgot to put the second link in the question. I just edited it right now. And I dont believe rotating fixed the issue.

Comment: I  dont believe rotating helped. The game is in portait but the phone is sideways. I want the game to be in potrait when the phone is upright. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bXdo.png